# ServicePoint safety checks to prevent blocking on new HttpWebRequests

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, servicepoint

I'm using a 3rd party library that makes a number of http calls. By decompiling the code, I've determined that it is creating and using raw `HttpWebRequest`'s, all going to a single URL. The issue is that some of the requests don't get closed properly. After some time, all new `HttpWebRequest`'s block forever when the library calls GetRequestStream()* on them. I've determined this blocking is due to the ConnectionLimit on the ServicePoint for that particular host, which has the default value of 2.  In other words, the library has opened 2 requests, and then tries to open a 3rd, which blocks.

I want to protect against this blocking. The library is fairly resilient and will reconnect itself, so it's okay if I kill the existing connections it has made.  The problem is that I don't have access to any of the `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpWebResponse`s this library makes. However I do know the URL it accesses and therefore I can access the `ServicePoint` for it.

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://UrlThatIKnowAbout.com"));
```

(Note: KeepAlive is enabled on these HttpWebRequests)

Comment: If you solved your problem, please write a helpful explanation of the steps you took for others who may find themselves in a similar situation in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @jonathan I made an educated guess and proposed 3 steps in my question as the solution, and it ended up working. What's the confusion?

Comment: Your answer couldn't stand on its own. You said "I did this, and it worked." The reader is left wondering what "this" and "it" refer to, as was evident in the comment left before deletion. Please feel free to write out an answer that is able to stand on its own. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan, I am also interested in how the TCP connection is established - however I couldn't find reference when I am looking at the assembly in ilsphy? do you have any luck? if yes, can you give me some advise? Basically I am trying to understand samething as yours 'I was interested to learn that GetRequestStream() establishes a TCP connection with the remote server, while GetResponse() actually sends the request' - how http webrequest creates tcp connections, manages them?

Comment: I think I understand details little better I guess (for details): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800216/how-and-where-the-tcp-connection-has-been-created-in-httpwebrequest-and-how-is

Comment: I was interested to learn that `GetRequestStream()` establishes a TCP connection with the remote server, while `GetResponse()` actually sends the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked, though I'm not sure it's the best way to solve the problem.

1. Get the service point object for the url
   `var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://UrlThatIKnowAbout.com"));`
2. Increase the `ConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue`
3. Create a background thread that periodically checks the `ConnectionCount` on the service point. If it goes above 5, call `CloseConnectionGroup()`
4. Set `MaxIdleTime` to 1 hour (instead of default)

Setting the `ConnectionLimit` should prevent the blocking. The monitor thread will ensure that too many connections are never active at the same time. Setting `MaxIdleTime` should serve as a fall back.